# Maven encrypt properties

Tags: java, maven

I am on the project, where some developers can read encrypted properties and some not. I need something like

```
<properties>
     <database.password>someHash</database.password>
</property>
```

and then in the configuration file using filtering I would like to have(@ is due to Spring Boot):

```
password=@database.password@
```

The property file would be during compilation compiled into:

```
password=superSecretPassword
```

I thought that [Maven Password Encryption](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) would help, but after some tries, I cannot manage to work it like that.
I also found [Properties maven plugin](http://site.kuali.org/maven/plugins/properties-maven-plugin/1.1.9/encrypt-mojo.html), but also without any success to achieve the desired solution.

Do you have some approach how to store encrypted properties into pom.xml and then decrypt them during compilation after entering some password?

Comment: First things first, why are you storing passwords in the POM? That should never happen, encrypted or not.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tunaki point's out, you should avoid having passwords in your pom, or anywhere in the source code for that matter.  One way to obtain encrypted credentials is to create a custom implementation of Springs PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Then, you could override postProcessBeanFactory() to perform encryption/decryption of your credential property files.  During decryption, you can simply call setProperties() with the decrypted property values.  In your spring configuration, you would use the property placeholders rather than the plain-text property values.

Note that you'll want to use a two-way encryption scheme rather than a message digest (or hash function) since you'll need to recover the plain-text credentials in order to create your database connections.